# How to use 'like [table1].[column1] & "*"' in a query

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to set up a query that will append a wildcard to the end of the value pulled from a joined table. My primary table is a list of all ICD codes assigned at a specific visit and my secondary table is a list of ICD codes that I want to find in my primary table.

The codes in the secondary table are not always complete, however. For example, the ICD code F84.1 in my primary table may be listed as F84 (meaning F84.0-F84.9 are applicable) in the secondary table I had tried:

```
SELECT a.DX_icd, a.Visit_date
FROM Diagnosis AS a INNER JOIN Criteria_ICD.ICD AS b on a.DX_ICD=b.ICD
WHERE a.DX_icd like "*" & b.ICD & "*"
```

However that returned no results. I've tried every combination of " vs ' and * vs %.

This query will run correctly:

```
Parameters code text(20);
SELECT *
FROM Diagnosis AS a
WHERE a.ICD like "*" & code & "*"
```

But is not practical, since I need to pull multiple codes. All fields I'm interacting with are short text and indexed.

EDITS for clarity:

Primary table:
ID |  Date  |  ICD
1  | 1/1/19 | F84.2 
2  | 1/2/19 | F83.9
3  | 1/2/19 | F84.0
4  | 1/3/19 | G93.3

Secondary table:
ICD
F84
Z00
G93

Desired output:
ID |  Date  |  ICD
1  | 1/1/19 | F84.2 
3  | 1/2/19 | F84.0
4  | 1/3/19 | G93.3

Comment: I am confused about your query.   You are already joining table A with table B by matching ICD code.   Based on you query, try removing the WHERE clause entirely

Comment: Also confused. Query has INNER JOIN clause with exact matching which means only records with matching values will be returned and the WHERE clause is meaningless. If no records return then there are no matches. Edit question to show sample raw data and desired output. Clarify which tables are primary and secondary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand what you are trying to achieve.

```
   SELECT a.DX_icd, a.Visit_date
    FROM Diagnosis AS a INNER JOIN Criteria_ICD.ICD AS b on a.DX_ICD=b.ICD
    WHERE a.DX_icd like "*" & b.ICD & "*"
```

Try this

```
   SELECT a.DX_icd, a.Visit_date
    FROM Diagnosis AS a 
    INNER JOIN Criteria_ICD.ICD AS b on a.DX_ICD  LIKE "*" &b.ICD & "*"
```

Comment: That did it! Seems so simple now. Thank you!